# "Delete from" OrientDB performance is low (delete is slow)

Tags: orientdb

I have stored about 85,000,000 Edges in my OrientDB (v 2.2.3) (85M) and similar number of vertices, I tried to clean the database by first running the command:

```
Delete from V UNSAFE
```

on the console it was very slow, so I left it running till the next day.

When I came the next day I ran the command

```
Delete from E UNSAFE
```

from the console also it took about 3 hours to delete the 85M edges

Is there anything wrong?

I think the performance should be way better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is the [TRUNCATE CLASS](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Truncate-Class.html) command, which is super fast if you don't have indexes.

Answer (score 0):

to completely clean the DB why not drop then recreate the database? it should be fast.

Comment: This is a valid option, but in some cases you have to run the command from API